# Getting error while connecting first time Toad my sql?

Tags: mysql

Getting Access denied error while I connect root user without password.

[image]

Comment: I guess root user needs a password

Comment: Please see the help section on how to post questions, please change your question accordingly. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what can be the password of root ?and if i want to reset password how can i?